# The code I'm using for my discord bot to delete a certain message based on a list of words deletes everything. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is the code:

```
const bannedwords = ["example word", "another example"]

client.on("message", message => {
if (message.content === bannedwords);
message.delete(message);

message.author.send("That was inappropriate!")
```

The error thrown is just an API saying cannot send a message to this user, nothing else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From what you pasted, your code is a bit wonky in the format. I have added a some function that will check if any substring in your list is in message.content and then if detected it will then delete and send a message to the author.

```
const bannedwords = ["example word", "another example"]

client.on("message", message => {
    // Checks if any banned words in the list are in message.content
    if (bannedwords.some((word) => message.content.includes(word))) {
        message.delete(message);
        message.author.send("That was inappropriate!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code to fix the banned words check, added in a bot check and replaced the semi-colon after the if-statement with curly brackets:

```js
const bannedwords = ["example word", "another example"];

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (new RegExp(bannedwords.join("|")).test(message.content)) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send("That was inappropriate!");
  }
});
```

The error you received saying that you cannot DM a user was probably caused by the bot trying to DM itself, and you can't DM a bot.